# Remove an element from a list that contains only NA?

Tags: r

I want to remove all elements in this list that contain only NA:

```
  List_data <- list("Green", "Yellow", c(NA,NA,NA), TRUE, 51.2)
```

Comment: Though a simple question, there is a little ambiguity. I think the two answers handle the possible scenarios, but in the future it would be nice to provide the expected output.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you mean *remove the entire element* (and not leave the empty name behind), try:

```
Filter(function(a) any(!is.na(a)), List_data)
```

**Edit**: using Onyambu's suggestion (thanks!) of `Negate(anyNA)`, this would be

```
Filter(Negate(anyNA), List_data)
```

though admittedly this changes the logic from *"something not-NA exists"* (first code) to *"no NA exists"* (second code), definitely a logical change.

Comment: or in the context of Onyambu answer + comments: `Filter(Negate(anyNA), List_data)`.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the two solutions give a different result with this example:
`mt <- mtcars; mt[1:3,1] <- NA; List_data <- list(iris=head(iris), allmiss=NA, mtcars=head(mt))`. Be careful!

Comment: In my case the first solution is better because it removes the element only if it is "all NA", but keeps an element if it has "some NA".

Answer (score 9):

For a `purrr` approach:

```
library(purrr)

List_data %>%
  map(discard, is.na) %>%
  compact()
```

Noting you can remove `compact()` and get "either" solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do:

```
List_data[!sapply(List_data, function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
```

or as @snoram pointed out:

```
 List_data[sapply(List_data, Negate(anyNA))]
```

which can also be expressed as:

```
 List_data[!sapply(List_data, anyNA)]
```

Comment: Was about to post: `List_data[sapply(List_data, function(x) !anyNA(x))]` but too similar to yours.

Comment: +1 for Negate(). From documentation: *anyNA implements any(is.na(x)) in a possibly faster way (especially for atomic vectors).*

Answer (score 6):

***EDIT2:*** As per akrun's comment following may also help here.

```
List_data[vapply(List_data, function(x) any(!is.na(x)), logical(1))]
```

---

***EDIT:*** As per Onyambu's comment following may help in order to remove complete element which has NA in it, thanks to Onyambu for guiding here.

```
List_data[!sapply(List_data, function(x) all(is.na(x)))]
```

---

---

Could you please try following:

```
lapply(List_data, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

Comment: I don't think this does what OP wants

Comment: @DavidArenburg, apologies David I thought OP wants to remove NA's so I tried this simple code, kindly do let me know if I missed something here.

Comment: Or use `List_data[vapply(List_data, function(x) any(!is.na(x)), logical(1))]`